# isapnp file missing in proc directory not able to get the information

Tags: linux, opensuse

not able to find the /proc/isapnp file in my Linux-4.1.36
I am trying to lists installed Plug and Play (PnP) cards in ISA slots on the system.
using:- cat /proc/isapnp command

Comment: What computer are you using? Unless it's about 20 years old, I seriously doubt it still has ISA slots. You can list PNP devices on the sort-of-ISA-bus-but-a-replacement of modern systems with `lspnp` (as root).

Comment: i am using dell-inspiron 3000 series with i3 core...doing lspnp it is showing command not found

Comment: i3 definitely has no ISA slots, it has been replaced by [LPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Pin_Count). In Debian, `lspnp` is part of the `pnputils` package. If OpenSuse doesn't have any equivalent, have a look at `/sys/bus/pnp/`, e.g. `cat /sys/bus/pnp/devices/*/id`.`dmesg` after boot also contains information.

Comment: After **cat/sys/bus/pnp/devices/*/id** it is showing only pnp no, not the full info like **cat /proc/isapnp** shows

PNP0c02
PNP0b00
INT3f0d
PNP0c02
PNP0c02
PNP0303
DLL065a
SYN0600
SYN0002
PNP0f13
PNP0c02
PNP0c02

Comment: Yes. You looked at the rest of the directory structure? You'll have to pick out the info from that, unless you find a working `lspnp`. Yes, it's a lot of work.